# Passing numpy arrays from dataframe after using groupby into a function that returns numpy arrays before appending back to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

If i have a dataframe with 2 groups,

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Date   | Code  | Input  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/1/18 | A     | 10     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/1/18 | B     | 100    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/2/18 | A     | 11     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/2/18 | B     | 101    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I first apply groupby to the code to get the following,

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Date   | Code  | Input  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/1/18 | A     | 10     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/2/18 | A     | 11     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/1/18 | B     | 100    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/2/18 | B     | 101    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I then pass the inputs according to the code and date to a function that only takes in and returns a numpy array

```
def func([10, 11]):
    returns [20, 25]

def func([100, 101]):
    returns [97, 95]
```

How can I join the numpy array to the corresponding date and code in the original order to get the intended dataframe below:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Date   | Code  | Input  | Output
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/1/18 | A     | 10     | 20
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/1/18 | B     | 100    | 97
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/2/18 | B     | 11     | 25
--------------------------------------------------
| 1/2/18 | B     | 101    | 95
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with simple slicing.

First create dataframes to work with

```
cols = ['Code', 'Input]
index = pd.date_range('20180101', '20180105', freq='1D')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 2)), index=index, columns=cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 2)), index=index, columns=cols)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

Identify rows you want to pass into your function.  Note: This is only an example, this can be modified to operate on a column instead of the index.

```
idx = df3.index==df3.index[0]

>>> df3.loc[idx, :]
Out[21]: 
               Code  Input
    2018-01-01    A      1
    2018-01-01    B      0
```

You can then grab data from this slice and pass it into your function.

```
>>> df3.loc[idx, 'Input'].values
Out[21]: 

       array([1, 0])  # see, it's an array.
```

You can add the row to df3 by passing the output of your function via

```
df3.loc[idx, 'Output'] = yourFunction(df3.loc[idx, 'Input'].values)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the swift response.

    data = {'date': ['1/1/2018', '1/1/2018', '1/2/2018', '1/2/2018'],
        'code': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'input': [10, 100, 11, 101]}

    df_market = pd.DataFrame(data)

I tried your suggestion but the index does not sort according to code, I am thinking of using groupby to get the array instead. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This works for me using the example you gave in your comment.  Are you setting idx = df_market.date==df_market.loc[0, 'date']?